# A download script and statcounter working together without opening a new page

Tags: php, javascript

I have this download script running that allows people to click on a button and download a file without any new html pages opening. It all works well. Here is the script.

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=brochure-company-details.pdf');
header('Content-type: pdf');
readfile('brochure-company-details.pdf');
?>
```

However, I really want to be able to run the statcounter script at the same time, so as to document who is downloading the file. The Statcounter script works well enough when an html page opens and runs through its function. But I down't want a new page to open. I just want the download to start. The user experience will be that they only have the file download and without them knowing the statcounter will record the event.

Can you help?

Comment: Sorry I could not understand, but if you want to count downloads it is just like for any other page, just write custom mysqli code in that file when download takes place.

Comment: Interesting idea, can you give some more information

Comment: On the page use a javascript onclick event to trigger the download and record the visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible. (executing javascript on pdf download) Statcounter is an  script and is executed by the browser by being included on the html. If you download a pdf file, you are not executing any js.

*However*, statcounter can see what links are pressed and therefore you can find which files were downloaded; as long your files are downloaded by using regular links on an html that has statcounter included. You don't need to do anything at all, they would be counted by default.

The idea Dachi gave, is to add an sql insertion to that php code of yours.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:/path/to/database.sdb");
//Put the insertion code here. 
//Insert things like the IP, the login name, the time, etc. 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=brochure-company-details.pdf');
header('Content-type: pdf');
readfile('brochure-company-details.pdf');
```

That works too, and is a good choice if you are allowing downloads by not using regular links or not from an html that has statcounter.

Comment: Thanks for that. This could be worth investigating... I will evaluate and advise others when I have implemented. Cheers